# Rails Tutorial 7.2.2 UsersController issue

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I'm in section 7.2.2 (Chapter 7) of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, and when I add an @user variable to `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` things get strange. The tests that are supposed to now pass don't - they instead fail for a different reason:

```
$ rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "signup page"

Failures:

1) User pages signup page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdec372a8e0>:0x007fdec375d010>
 # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___2884421820517152565_70297369620580'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User pages signup page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdec372a8e0>:0x007fdec45caee0>
 # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___2884421820517152565_70297369620580'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Initially, these tests fail b/c @user is nil. Now they're failing due to an undefined method.

The book suggests that they should pass once I've defined @user, so I'm confused. I've pushed ahead a bit thinking perhaps this would work itself out, but it hasn't, so I'd like to figure this out before proceeding.

Here are the tests in question (copied from the book):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do
  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
   let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
   before { visit signup_path }
   it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
   it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-opening the project from scratch I got a different error which led me to discover this typo in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
# Speed up tests by lowering BCrypt's cost function. require 'bcrypt'
silence_warnings do
  BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST
end
```

By moving `require 'bcrypt'` to it's own line, everything works again - including the tests in my original question.

```
# Speed up tests by lowering BCrypt's cost function. 
require 'bcrypt'
silence_warnings do
  BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST
end
```